# awk to sum the numbers(floating) and group it on a unique key

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to sum up the numbers and grouping it on a unique key but the sum output is sometimes shows as exponential and some time it shows as integer/floating after rounding off.

Input File

```
Id|LegNum|Amount1|Amount2|Location
123456|0|238157.5|4280338.799|CL
123456|1|8487.924693|2541829.5|CL
123456|1|14516.47036|31881.6|CL
123789|0|483773.787|10410.78659|CL
456789|0|1321034|1057203.46|NY
456789|1|65802|4913.79677|NY
567890|0|683651.0865|533.617279|IN
567890|0|705864.844|907210|IN
```

using below awk to sum and group it at first and second column

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|"; OFS = FS;} NR==1 {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5;next}{a[$1"|"$2]+=$3;b[$1"|"$2]+=$4;c[$1"|"$2]=$5;}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i],b[i],c[i]}' InputFile.txt >> output.txt
```

output.txt shows the sums as exponential OR after rounding off as mentioned below.

```
Id|LegNum|Amount1|Amount2|Location
123789|0|483774|10410.8|CL
123456|0|238158|4.28034e+06|CL
567890|0|1.38952e+06|907744|IN
123456|1|23004.4|2.57371e+06|CL
456789|0|1321034|1.0572e+06|NY
456789|1|65802|4913.8|NY
```

But I want the output as floating (without rounding off) if the number is floating and as integer if the number is integer. and definitely don't want the exponential output.

Comment: You should be able to use `printf` with `%f` to print floating point.

Comment: but at which place, I should use it. i tried to print using  **{for(i in a)printf "%f\n" i,a[i],b[i],c[i]}** but didn't work as expected

Comment: @AmitSingh If you are using `printf()`, you will have to specify the format for _each_ individual parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` uses its `OFMT` variable as the default `printf` format for outputting numbers.  This is `%.6g` by default.

You may set this to something like `%f` or to a more precise format appropriate for your data, or you may want to use `printf()` instead of `print` to format the output explicitly.

Example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print 100000000.10, 2, "hello" }'
1e+08 2 hello

$ awk -vOFMT='%f' 'BEGIN { print 100000000.10, 2, "hello" }'
100000000.100000 2 hello

$ awk -vOFMT='%.2f' 'BEGIN { print 100000000.10, 2, "hello" }'
100000000.10 2 hello

$ awk 'BEGIN { printf("%.2f %d %s\n", 100000000.10, 2, "hello") }'
100000000.10 2 hello
```