# Need full decimals in awk sum when summing decimal values

Tags: awk

I've the following test.txt file -

```
var,value
a,1.1234
b,1.7896749
c,2.4982
d,1.2976232
```

When I use the following command -

```
awk -F ',' '{SUM+=$2}END{print SUM}' test.txt
```

it prints **6.7089**

But the result with all the decimal places is **6.7088981**
How can write the command so that it prints all the decimal places in the result, not just in this specific case but in general. For example, if the result has 10 decimal places, it should print all the 10 decimal places? If the result has only 5 decimal places, it should print only 5 decimal places. 
The OS that I'm using is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.7

Comment: That's not necessarily the result. See https://floating-point-gui.de/ or just google "floating point arithmetic". Try `awk -F ',' '{SUM+=$2}END{printf "%.20f\n", SUM}' file` and you'll get an output like `6.70889810000000075263`

Comment: You're likely seeing the effect of the default `OFMT` (which is `%.6g` iirc). See related [awk to sum the numbers(floating) and group it on a unique key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453551/awk-to-sum-the-numbersfloating-and-group-it-on-a-unique-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon printing, non-integer numbers are converted to decimal string representation using the `OFMT` special variable which contains a `printf` format specification (by default `%.6g`). You can change it to `%.17g` to get the maximum precision of IEEE 754 double precision binary floating point numbers (as used internally by most `awk` implementations on most systems). Another variable (`CONVFMT`) is used in the other cases where a floating point numbers are  implicitly converted to strings (like when you concatenate a number with something else)

You won't get more precision with those doubles, there's no point going beyond 17. Already with 17, you're likely to see some artifacts. 15 significant digits may be better if you don't need that much precision.

```
$ awk -v OFMT=%.17g -F ',' '{SUM+=$2};END{print SUM}' < file
6.7088981000000008
$ awk -v OFMT=%.15g -F ',' '{SUM+=$2};END{print SUM}' < file
6.7088981
```

While `OFMT` affects all printed floating point numbers, you could also use `printf` directly to print numbers with the required precision.

```
$ awk  -F ',' '{SUM+=$2};END{printf "%.15g\n", SUM}' < file
6.7088981
```

The GNU implementation of `awk`, since version 4.1.0 can also be compiled with arbitrary precision arithmetics support (see `info gawk 'Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic'`). If that's the case on your system, you could also do:

```
gawk -M -v PREC=256 -v OFMT=%.60g -F ',' '{SUM+=$2};END{print SUM}' < file
```

Example:

```
$ printf 'x,%s\n' 1 1000000000000000000000000000000000.00000000001 |
> gawk -v OFMT=%.15g -F ',' '{SUM+=$2};END{print SUM}'
999999999999999945575230987042816
$ printf 'x,%s\n' 1 1000000000000000000000000000000000.00000000001 |
> gawk -M -v PREC=256 -v OFMT=%.60g -F ',' '{SUM+=$2};END{print SUM}'
1000000000000000000000000000000001.00000000001
```

Another approach here could be to use `bc` (assuming those numbers are always expressed like that (`0.001`, not `1e-3` for instance)):

```
<file tail -n+2 | # skip header
  cut -d, -f2   | # extract second field
  paste -sd + - | # join input lines with +
  bc
```

The number of digits after the `.` will be the maximum in any input record.

Comment: Thank you. When I change the second row value to 100000000000.7896749, then the expected result should be 100000000005.708898. That's happening only with your last command <file tail -n+2 | cut -d, -f2 | paste -sd + | bc

Comment: @GiveSeek, yes that number has 19 significant decimal digits, more than a IEEE 754   `double` can store, so only *arbitrary precision* approaches will work. I take it your `gawk` doesn't support `-M`.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) displays the number in the desired precision with its default output settings:

```
$ datamash --header-in -t, sum 2 < test.txt
6.7088981
```

Or awk with a different `OFMT` with more precision:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFMT='%.10g' '{sum += $2} END { print sum }' test.txt
6.7088981
```

but see [Is Floating-Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). The number of digits after the decimal point when a floating point number is displayed in base 10 doesn't always correspond to the IEEE754, base 2 representation that (most) computers use.

Answer (score 1):

As already discussed, floating point arithmetic is the problem when trying to get the intuitive answer but if you know your input can only have up to, say, 3 digits before the "." and, say, 9 after it then you could convert your numbers to decimals using string manipulation, then sum those to avoid the floating point arithmetic issue, and then convert the result back to FP again before printing, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
    bef = 3
    aft = 9
}
NR>1 {
    split($2,f,".")
    val = sprintf("%*s%-*s",bef,f[1],aft,f[2])
    gsub(/ /,0,val)
    sum += val
}
END {
    sub(".{"aft"}$",".&",sum)
    sub(/0+$/,"",sum)
    print sum
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
6.7088981
```

If 3 and/or 9 aren't large enough numbers for you, pick other numbers or do a 2-pass approach that figures out the max for each on the first pass, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "," }
FNR==1 { next }
{ split($2,f,".") }
NR==FNR {
    bef = (length(f[1]) > bef ? length(f[1]) : bef)
    aft = (length(f[2]) > aft ? length(f[2]) : aft)
    next
}
{
    val = sprintf("%*s%-*s",bef,f[1],aft,f[2])
    gsub(/ /,0,val)
    sum += val
}
END {
    sub(".{"aft"}$",".&",sum)
    sub(/0+$/,"",sum)
    print sum
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
6.7088981
```